# Facebook Like button issue where "like" occurs on different page than currently viewing in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, facebook-like

I'm having an issue where facebook "like" buttons are liking a category page rather than a single post in wordpress. I've tried using both the "Facebook Likes it!" plugin (currently using this one) and the "Easy Facebook Like Button" plugin.

Initially the like button would "like" the single post page and send it to facebook, but now it is "liking" the category url instead on some posts.

Here are URL's for example:

1)Main category page for one Artist. Note the like button on the left. It "likes" the artist.
http://envisionart.org/category/artists/christian/

2)Click on the first post, and it will automatically have you like the "post" if you already liked the artist, and it sends the "like" information to facebook as the same information as in #1 above
http://envisionart.org/artists/christian/atmospheric-perspective-3/

3)Same artist, third post. This post allows the end-user to "like" the post vs. the artist. I'm stumped as to why.
http://envisionart.org/artists/christian/bat-artist-trading-card/

Any help would be wonderful. I'll gladly post some code on request.

Also, check out these pages to cross-reference. Same setup, but I have no issues with the like buttons:
http://envisionart.org/category/programs/camps/

I'm stumped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>
```

Example..

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```